# How to speed up extracting data from msg attachments in Outlook emails using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, outlook, email-attachments

I have an Outlook/Exchange folder with ~8000 emails. Every email has a .msg attachment, i.e. an email inside an email.

I'm extracting:

- date received
- sender email
- category
- attached email: date received
- attached email: sender email
- attached email: sender domain
- attached email: recipient (can be 0, 1 or many email addresses)
- attached email: subject

Outlook has a limitation that you cannot manipulate email attachments in-memory, you first need to save them to disk.

My current workflow:

- loop over all emails in the folder
- in each email, loop over all attachments
- if the attachment has extension .msg, save it to a temp folder
- import the just saved .msg file into a temp Outlook folder
- read the data from the imported email using the Outlook/MAPI VBA API

I did a test run on the emails of 1 month. 251 emails were processed at a speed of 43.5 emails/minute. Extrapolating to the entire folder, it would take 3 hours to process. Due to limitations in the environment, I am limited to VBA (not able to install something like Python). I also cannot install Extended MAPI or Redemption.

I'm doing some well-known speed optimizations:

- Option Explicit
- Turn off calculation, screenupdating, etc.
- I'm writing the results to a spreadsheet row per row instead of to an array first and then saving that to a range, because most of the time is spent on FileSystem and MAPI objects, and the Excel screenupdating is marginal.

I would appreciate other speed improvements that make it go faster more than just a few percents.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExtractPhishingEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMAPI As Object
    Dim phishingFolder As Object
    Dim extractionFolder As Object
    Dim phishingReport As Object
    Dim attachment As Object
    Dim tempFolderName As String
    Dim attachmentFileName As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim emailToImport As Object
    Dim recipient As Object
    Dim recipientList As String
    Dim senderEmail As Object
    Dim senderEmailAddress As String
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMAPI = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set phishingFolder = objMAPI _
        .Folders("REDACTED") _
        .Folders("Inbox") _
        .Folders("02. Reports") _
        .Folders("SPAM-PHISHING")
    Set extractionFolder = objMAPI _
        .GetDefaultFolder(6) _
        .Folders("phishing")
    tempFolderName = Environ("Temp")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PhishingReport")
    
    
    Debug.Print Now
    OnStart
    
    sheet.UsedRange.Delete
    sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Date Reported"
    sheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Reported by"
    sheet.Cells(1, 3) = "Category"
    sheet.Cells(1, 4) = "Date Received"
    sheet.Cells(1, 5) = "Spammer Email"
    sheet.Cells(1, 6) = "Spammer Domain"
    sheet.Cells(1, 7) = "Spam Recipient"
    sheet.Cells(1, 8) = "Mail Subject"
    currentRow = 1
    
    
    For Each phishingReport In _
            phishingFolder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=%lastmonth(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        DoEvents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        For Each attachment In phishingReport.Attachments
            If Right(attachment.FileName, 4) = ".msg" Then
                attachmentFileName = tempFolderName & "\" & attachment.FileName
                attachment.SaveAsFile attachmentFileName
                
                Set emailToImport = objMAPI.OpenSharedItem(attachmentFileName)
                emailToImport.Move extractionFolder
                
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
                
                sheet.Cells(currentRow, 1) = phishingReport.SentOn
                
                sheet.Cells(currentRow, 2) = phishingReport.sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")
                
                sheet.Cells(currentRow, 3) = phishingReport.Categories
                
                sheet.Cells(currentRow, 4) = emailToImport.ReceivedTime
                
                Set senderEmail = emailToImport.sender
                senderEmailAddress = getSmtpAddress(senderEmail)
                sheet.Cells(currentRow, 5) = senderEmailAddress
                
                sheet.Cells(currentRow, 6) = getDomain(senderEmailAddress)
                
                For Each recipient In emailToImport.Recipients
                    recipientList = _
                        recipientList _
                        + recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E") _
                        + ";"
                Next recipient
                sheet.Cells(currentRow, 7) = recipientList
                
                sheet.Cells(currentRow, 8) = emailToImport.Subject
                
                Set emailToImport = Nothing
                Set senderEmail = Nothing
                recipientList = ""
                objFSO.GetFile(attachmentFileName).Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next attachment
    Next phishingReport

    OnEnd
    Debug.Print Now

End Sub


Public Function getSmtpAddress(objEmailAddress As Object) As String
    If (InStr(objEmailAddress.Address, "@")) Then
        getSmtpAddress = objEmailAddress.Address
    Else
        getSmtpAddress = objEmailAddress.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")
    End If
End Function


Public Function getDomain(EmailAddress As String) As String
    getDomain = Split(EmailAddress, "@")(1)
End Function


Public Sub OnEnd()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub


Public Sub OnStart()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your Excel Workbook / AddIn in a trusted location (or code signed)? See point 4 'Which is better? Trusted Document or Trusted Location?' here https://isladogs.co.uk/trusted-location/index.html ... in this article, the author is talking about Access but the 'VBA / AMSI slow-down' will be the same in any VBA enabled app I imagine

Comment: Without knowing where the time is spent in the macro then it's hard to know how to help. 
Perhaps you can set up a timer that takes the time on each of the components of the code, that way we know if there is something that can be done or not. The only thing that I see that might do something is the delete `objFSO.GetFile(attachmentFileName).Delete`, this could either be done later or not at all (you use Explorer when the macro is done).

Comment: Check your temp folder is local and not associated with OneDrive or similar.
Also I've noticed using `With sheet ... End With` can shave time off bigger loops.
Also although most of the time is in the FileSystem and MAPI I would still recommend logging to an array and updating the workbook at the end.
Have you considered using Outlook VBA to handle the emails then write to Excel afterwards?

Comment: @JohnM unfortunately adding a trusted location brings my test run from 4 minutes to 6 minutes.

Comment: @Andreas fair enough. I'll add some timers, but it'll have to wait until after my holiday, so in two weeks.

Comment: @CHill60 The temp folder is on C:. I'll try `With sheet` after my holiday. I didn't use an array because then I don't see any progress at all and then I don't know if it hangs, but I guess I can watch the emails get added to the temp Outlook folder. Another issue with an array: it's all or nothing. If I interrupt the code, then I have zero data. Without an array and directly to worksheet, I at least have *some* data to examine. My initial code was using Outlook VBA, but then I couldn't send it to a colleage to let them run it, and in an xlsm it's nicely self contained. Will try after my holida

Comment: Couple ideas. Use a dictionary to cache already found results for the getSmtpAddress method. Looking up stuff in Active Directory can be slow.  Also, write values to an array instead of the sheet as you loop. Then write the data at once to a sheet from the array at the end. If you can use other languages there is Redemption(https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) which allows for multitasking and other cool features

Comment: The dictionary to cache getSmtpAddress is definitely something I will try when I get back from holiday. Write values to array: yes, I did that in my initial implementation. Downsides: I don't see any progress at all, and if I interrupt the code, then everything in memory is lost. When writing to the sheet inside the loop I at least have partial results. I cannot use other languages or install Redemption unfortunately. It's a locked down virtual desktop. I'd love to write it in Python but unfortunately peanut butter.

Comment: @CHill60 `With sheet ...` doesn't make any noticeable difference. It's also not a very big loop.

Comment: @RyanWildry I implemented a dictionary to cache results of `getSmtpAddress`. It doesn't have any measureable difference, but I'm leaving it in there because I like the idea, it is conceptually very elegant.

Comment: If you want to "watch" the progress update the application status bar with an appropriate message and/or the immediate window with Debug.Print. It will still be massively faster than updating a sheet. Also make sure Calculation mode is set to manual - you have it set to Automatic.

Comment: `Debug.Print`, in my experience, causes a considerable slowdown. So I won't do that. `Application.StatusBar` - yes, I already have that. Calculation - is already manual. The sheet updating is not the slowest part. It's the file I/O.

Comment: How do you solve the problem of "all or nothing" versus "at least _some_ partial data" with "in-memory array" versus "write to sheet"?